# What is the iPod Touch 6G media query?

Tags: css, media-queries, ipod, ipod-touch

I have been looking everywhere online for the iPod touch 6 generation media queries but I couldn't find anything useful. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you are on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution specific to your requirements.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 640px)  {

        /* STYLES GO HERE */
    }
```

In order to find out about the media queries of any device, simply Google to find out the screen resolution of the device and use that value for media query.

Comment: While it's helpful to link to external resources, you should include the relevant part in your answer. This ensures that the information will always be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The 6th generation iPod touch is a Retina display with a pixel width of 640px. This amounts to 320px with a ratio of 2.

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of most media queries:

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}